# How to fix"Open browser failed!! Please "in vscode

Tags: html, browser, visual-studio-code

I recently meet a awful problem in vscode with my html code,i used open-in-browser extension. And "Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome correctly!" appeared ,i have tried many ways and i still can't solve it. I tried to change the user setting and workspacesettings,but nothing works.
I really want to solve this problem
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Use View In Browser. It definitely works, and as for the theme, you can always get a similar one, there are thousands of them. ViewInBrowser can be put on a keyboard shortcut by going into the settings, and so It can be very easy to open your file. I use Sublime, not Vscode, so I don't know exactly how to fix that particular issue. You might make sure it is configured for that browser, and make sure you have compatibility with your version of the browser.